# XAML Grid column items do not expand evenly when screen width increases

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have some XAML code containing a grid with three columns. In these columns I added three buttons with images. When I increase the width of the screen, the second and third images move evenly towards the right but the first image, the leftmost one, stays put and does not move. It's like its left edge stays stuck to the left and does not move slowly towards the right when I expand the width of the screen.

Here is my code. I cannot figure out how to do this. Sorry I had to use an image, I'm getting the code from my VM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't bother to set the `HorizontalAlignement` ofthe buttons,
the default value is Left, that's why the first button wont move, set it to `Center`

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image  Source="img.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="img.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="img.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it didn't work. I still get the same behavior. Is it because it's a Universal Windows App? A lot of the standard WPF stuff does not work in a UWA. The DockPanel was even removed! Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: The HorizontalAlignment works perfect in Winrt (Universal apps included), unless you are doing something else in the codebehind/ViewModel that should works !

Comment: The only difference is that I used the Universal Windows App template from Visual Studio 2015. But it's not working.

Comment: Here the same code from a UnivApp template :
http://prntscr.com/85o0wy
http://prntscr.com/85o156

Comment: I clicked on your link but how do I see the code? I only see an image.

Comment: Yes i gave you a preview the code is the same above !